# Apply to each column in multiple dataframes

Tags: r, apply

If I were to find the class of each column I would normally (assuming I'd like to avoid `str`):

```
lapply(df, class)
```

However, what if I wanted to do the same for multiple dataframes? E.g.:

```
x <- data.table(col_1 = c('a', 'b')
                , col_2 = 1:2
                ); x

y <- data.table(col_3 = 3:4
                , col_4 = c('c', 'd')
                ); y
```

My attempt is:

```
lapply(1:2, function(i) class( list(x,y)[[i]] ) )
```

but it gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

[[2]]
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

i.e. `R` is failing to apply to the columns inside each element (in this case, each dataframe) of the list. If I am after an `apply` solution (especially not a `For loop` or `str`), what would that be?
Or would `Reduce`, `Map` or `do.call` achieve this too?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the datatables in a list and then use `lapply` to iterate over them.

```
lapply(list(x, y), function(x) sapply(x, class))

#[[1]]
#      col_1       col_2 
#"character"   "integer" 

#[[2]]
#      col_3       col_4 
#  "integer" "character"
```

Comment: How have you been? I still remember your help a few years back
So an apply within an apply. I went down the wrong route. Though still don't understand why mine didn't work
Thank you

Comment: I am doing good, hope you are well too. If `i = 1`, `list(x,y)[[1]]` returns the datatable and you are taking `class` of it. You actually want class of each column of the datatable i.e `lapply(1:2, function(i) sapply(list(x,y)[[i]], class))` would work but seems convoluted.

Comment: Ah, that's why. I missed the nested sapply. Too focused on the double square bracket `[[]]`
But yes, it is convoluted and can be streamlined i.e. yours and @Miff 's
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As `x` and `y` inherit from lists, they can be concatenated, so you can use

```
lapply(c(x,y), class)
# $col_1
# [1] "character"
# 
# $col_2
# [1] "integer"
# 
# $col_3
# [1] "integer"
# 
# $col_4
# [1] "character"
```

Comment: I see. So this concatenate all columns rather than treating them as separate `df`
Thanks too

Answer (score 2):

We may use

```
library(purrr)
map(c(x, y), class)
$col_1
[1] "character"

$col_2
[1] "integer"

$col_3
[1] "integer"

$col_4
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Indeed this also works. Am new to `purrr`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We could use base `R` `Map`:

```
Map(class,c(x,y))
```

```
$col_1
[1] "character"

$col_2
[1] "integer"

$col_3
[1] "integer"

$col_4
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Thank you, TarJae. I thought Map could be handy here.
Is there a way to preserve the separation of dataframes such as that solution from @Ronak Shah ?